How to display the fieldset in the specific level category in magento2?
I have created the custom attributes fieldset with field in it.
view/adminhtml/layout/ui_component/category_form.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product_category_custom_fields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item  name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Category Custom Fields(Hoarding Board)</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        
        <field name="heading" sortOrder="20">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Heading</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">heading</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
 </fieldset>
</form>

I want the fieldset with that field,to be display in the level 2 category only.
But that fieldset is displayed in each and every categories.
